Passport Login endpoint doesn't work in Laravel Sail
I installed sail and trying to work with docker container on my Laravel 8 project. I use passport package for authentication. When trying to log in to app, request waits in pending state and any other routes doesn't work, seems like app crashed. My sail version is 1.0.1, laravel framework 8.12 and passport version is 10.1. Following code is my login function:
$response = Http::asForm()->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);
        if ($response->successful()) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->username)->with('roles')->first();
            return response()->json(['tokenInfo' => $response->json(), 'userInfo' => $user], 200);
        } else {
            if ($response->clientError()) {
                return response()->json('Credential error.', 400);
            } else if ($response->serverError()) {
                return response()->json('Sunucu hatası.', 500);
            }
        }

I found a suggestion which offers to use laravel octane for server but I can't install it because of laravel framework version. What's the solution of this problem?

You try to login in external laravel app?

@Maksim I try to log in from vue frontend app to laravel api.

But why you use Http call?

What are the alternative ways to make login using passport ? I'm doing it according to laravel doc "https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens"

upgrade the laravel version. L8 is end of life -> no more support. plus grant_type password is not recommended, use authorization_code.

I upgraded to 9.5.2 and now request timeout error is returning.
